# Bootstrap ACTIVE Navigation link

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I already set up my active class in my navigation but what I want to do is when I want to visit the other pages in the navigation, I want to change the active class to that specific navigation. Please help thanks

Comment: Change the active class to the appropriate <li> on each page

Comment: Please provide a minimal code example and also mention and whats running on you server. PHP, ASP or any other.

Comment: Oh yes, I'm in Laravel. How can i use it in Blade Template? because in the master page I can only specify one link to be active